# Assigning value to arg with val object(arg) = object

Tags: scala

I am following [this](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-scala/2-preparing-first-query/) tutorial on GraphQL with Sangria. I am wondering about the following line

```
val JsObject(fields) = requestJSON
```

where `requestJSON` is an object of `JsValue`. This way of assigning `fields` is new to me and my question is, if you could name that pattern or provide me with a link to a tutorial regarding this structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [Extractor](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html) pattern, you can reach the same result implementing the unapply method on your arbitrary object (like shown in the example). When you create a `case class` the compiler produces an unapply method for you, so you can do:

```
case class Person(name : String, surname : String)
val person = Person("gianluca", "aguzzi")
val Person(name, surname) = person
```

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to know is that `val` definitions support a *Pattern* on the left-hand side of the assignment, thus providing (subset of the functionality of) Pattern Matching.

So, your example is equivalent to:

```scala
val fields = requestJSON match {
  case JsObject(foo) => foo
}
```

See [Scala Language Specification Section 4.1 *Value Declarations and Definitions*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions) for details.

So, for example, if you have a list `l` and you want to assign the first element and the rest, you could write:

```scala
val x :: xs = l
```

Or, for the fairly common case where a method returns a tuple, you could write:

```scala
val (result1, result2) = foo()
```